# SSRS Not Loading record in browser for only large data

Tags: reporting-services

I don't have any problem when i am testing my SSRS Report in Business Intelligence(33000 records) and parameter filters are also working well.
Based on the date range,it was automatically filter the Itemgroup,Itemcode,TestType,Batch.And Based on Itemgroup values it was filter Itemcode,Testtype and Batch and so on...
but,After deployed,once i select 'select all' values, In the Internet Explorer is not show any record when i click View report,Even not loading.But if i select the itemgroup values in limited amount(less than 5 values) in multi value selection, it was working fine.but if i select more than 5 values in multi value selection no response when i was clicking view report (refer the figure 2). 
1. Why wasn't load and not shown any result for select all values?
2. why wasn't selected all values defaultly for Itemcode,Test Type,BatchNo when i change the itemgroup values? (In parameters,i fixed dataset values for Available Values,Default values already for itemcode,itemgrup,testtype,batchNo).
(Note: My last parameter(batchNumber) have 10000 distinct values).

```
My_Stored Procedure
-------------------

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SIVA_ControlLimitGenerator]
@frmdat as date,
@todat as date
AS
drop table SIVA_ControlLimit
if (@frmdat is not null or @frmdat<>'') and (@todat is not null or @todat<>'')
begin
select * into SIVA_ControlLimit from (SELECT 
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[QUALITYORDERID] AS 'QC_NO',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[ITEMID] AS 'ITEM_FULLID',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[TESTGROUPID] AS 'ITEM_CODE',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[QTY],
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[INVENTDIMID],
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME] AS 'VALIDATE_DATE',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[TESTID] AS 'TEST_TYPE',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[STANDARDVALUE],
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[LOWERLIMIT] AS 'MIN',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[UPPERLIMIT] AS 'MAX',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[TESTUNITID] AS 'TEST_UNIT',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[PM_ORDERRESULT] AS 'ORDER_RESULT',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[PM_ORDERSTATUS]AS 'ORDER_STATUS',
[dbo].[INVENTDIM].[INVENTBATCHID] AS 'BATCH_NO',
[dbo].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMGROUPID] AS 'ITEM_GROUP'
FROM [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE] ON [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[QUALITYORDERID]=[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[QUALITYORDERID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTDIM] ON [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[INVENTDIMID] =[dbo].[INVENTDIM].[INVENTDIMID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTTABLE] ON [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[ITEMID]=[dbo].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMID]
WHERE [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[DATAAREAID] = N'adk'
AND YEAR([dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME])>=2014 and YEAR([dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME])<=YEAR(GETDATE())
and [dbo].[INVENTTABLE].[DATAAREAID] =N'adk' and [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME]>=@frmdat and [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME]<=@todat)n
end
else
begin
select * into SIVA_ControlLimit from (SELECT 
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[QUALITYORDERID] AS 'QC_NO',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[ITEMID] AS 'ITEM_FULLID',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[TESTGROUPID] AS 'ITEM_CODE',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[QTY],
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[INVENTDIMID],
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME] AS 'VALIDATE_DATE',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[TESTID] AS 'TEST_TYPE',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[STANDARDVALUE],
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[LOWERLIMIT] AS 'MIN',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[UPPERLIMIT] AS 'MAX',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[TESTUNITID] AS 'TEST_UNIT',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[PM_ORDERRESULT] AS 'ORDER_RESULT',
[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[PM_ORDERSTATUS]AS 'ORDER_STATUS',
[dbo].[INVENTDIM].[INVENTBATCHID] AS 'BATCH_NO',
[dbo].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMGROUPID] AS 'ITEM_GROUP'
FROM [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE] ON [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[QUALITYORDERID]=[dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERLINE].[QUALITYORDERID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTDIM] ON [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[INVENTDIMID] =[dbo].[INVENTDIM].[INVENTDIMID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[INVENTTABLE] ON [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[ITEMID]=[dbo].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMID]
WHERE [dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[DATAAREAID] = N'adk'
AND YEAR([dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME])>=2014 and YEAR([dbo].[INVENTQUALITYORDERTABLE].[VALIDATEDDATETIME])<=YEAR(GETDATE()))n
end
*Dataset*
------------
    Execute SIVA_ControlLimitGenerator @FromDate,@ToDate
select * from SIVA_ControlLimit where
((VALIDATE_DATE>=@FromDate and VALIDATE_DATE<=@ToDate) or (@FromDate is null and  @ToDate is null)) 
and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) order by BATCH_NO
Filter DataSet(Parameters)
---------------------------
*1.Item group*
--------------
    SELECT distinct ITEM_GROUP from SIVA_ControlLimit
WHERE ((VALIDATE_DATE>=@FromDate and VALIDATE_DATE<=@ToDate) or (@FromDate is null and  @ToDate is null)) order by ITEM_GROUP
*2.Item code*
-------------
    SELECT distinct ITEM_CODE from SIVA_ControlLimit
WHERE 
((VALIDATE_DATE>=@FromDate and VALIDATE_DATE<=@ToDate) or (@FromDate is null and  @ToDate is null)) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP) order by ITEM_CODE
*3.Test Type*
-------------
    SELECT distinct TEST_TYPE from SIVA_ControlLimit
WHERE ((VALIDATE_DATE>=@FromDate and VALIDATE_DATE<=@ToDate) or (@FromDate is null and  @ToDate is null)) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP) order by TEST_TYPE
*4.Batch*
--------
    SELECT distinct BATCH_NO from SIVA_ControlLimit
WHERE ((VALIDATE_DATE>=@FromDate and VALIDATE_DATE<=@ToDate) or (@FromDate is null and  @ToDate is null)) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and ITEM_GROUP in (@ITEM_GROUP)
 order by BATCH_NO
```

[image: Please Refer the picture]
[image: Please Refer the picture]
Can any one suggest me a good solution?...

Thanks......

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: When you say not working in ie, what does that mean?

Comment: 33,000 records is not large data. But, are the cascading parameters based on the date range entered? And is it running the report query to get the cascading parameters?

Comment: yes Mr.WEI_DBA. Anyway i edited my question, please read it once again...thanks.

Comment: @Ross Bush: If i select 'select all' values in parameters based on date range it was working and shows result in Business Intelligence when i click view report. but once i deployed, In IE, it was not shown any values even not loading when i click view report. Thanks...

Comment: thank u all...I found the solution. parameter maximum value is 1000, but my last parameter had 10000. that's why it was not loading when i am selecting 'select all' option.